# How to get columns out of (2, 64) dimension dataframe of different data types without having null values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, types

This is may be a very simple but I am not able to find a way forward. I have a dataframe with columns having different datatypes as shown below:[image]

Now, I need to find those columns(years) for which we have values in both rows(i.e. omit columns with null values). I tried below code and could get the columns which have values in both the rows.

```
Iran.columns[~Iran.isnull().any()]
```

**Output:**

```
Index(['Country Name', 'Country Code', 'Indicator Name', 'Indicator Code',
       '1960', '1961', '1962', '1963', '1964', '1965', '1966', '1967', '1968',
       '1969', '1970', '1971', '1972', '1973', '1974', '1975', '1976', '1977',
       '1978', '1979', '1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986',
       '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997',
       '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006',
       '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015',
       '2016', '2017'],
      dtype='object')
```

My problem is that I am also getting 'Country Name', 'Country Code', 'Indicator Name', 'Indicator Code' columns as well which are not required. I am not able to think a way through.

I actually have world bank data for Population and GDP in two separate dataframes. From there, I created this 'Iran' name dataframe after concatenation from parent dataframes to solve this question: **What years do we have complete data (GDP and Population) for Iran?**
I just need to find answer in simple and neat way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63930601/what-does-it-mean-to-add-gaussian-noise-0-05-in-scikit-learn-make-circle-ho

Comment: Thanks @stackoverflowuser2010  Your answer is very detailed. Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select a subset of your data in a new df, with only those column names that are numeric, for example (or a regex for 4 digits) and filter out everything that has blanks. then get the remaining column values with:

```
df.columns.tolist()
```