# What does it mean to add gaussian noise = 0.05 in scikit-learn make_circle()? How will it affect the data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on hyperparameter tuning of neural networks and going through examples. I came across this code in one example:

```
train_X, train_Y = sklearn.datasets.make_circles(n_samples=300, noise=.05)
```

I understand that adding noise has regularization effect on data. Reading the documentation for this tells that it adds guassian noise. However, in above code, I could not understand what does it means to add `0.05` noise in the data. How would this affect data mathematically here?

I tried below code. I could see values changing but could not figure out how, for example, row1 values of x in array 1 changed by adding `noise= .05` to corresponding row in array 2 i.e. x_1 here?

```
np.random.seed(0)
x,y = sklearn.datasets.make_circles()
print(x[:5,:])

x_1,y_1 = sklearn.datasets.make_circles(noise= .05)
print(x_1[:5,:])
```

Output:

```
[[-9.92114701e-01 -1.25333234e-01]
 [-1.49905052e-01 -7.85829801e-01]
 [ 9.68583161e-01  2.48689887e-01]
 [ 6.47213595e-01  4.70228202e-01]
 [-8.00000000e-01 -2.57299624e-16]]

[[-0.66187208  0.75151712]
 [-0.86331995 -0.56582111]
 [-0.19574479  0.7798686 ]
 [ 0.40634757 -0.78263011]
 [-0.7433193   0.26658851]]
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_circles.html):

> sklearn.datasets.**make_circles**(n_samples=100, *, shuffle=True, noise=None, random_state=None, factor=0.8)
> Make a large circle containing a smaller circle in 2d. A simple toy dataset to visualize clustering and classification algorithms.
>
> **noise**: double or None (default=None)
> Standard deviation of Gaussian noise added to the data.

The statement `make_circles(noise=0.05)` means that it is creating random circles with a little bit of variation  following a [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), also known as a normal distribution. You should already know that a random Gaussian distribution means that the numbers being generated have some mean and standard definition. In this case, the call `make_circles(noise=0.05)` means that the standard deviation is 0.05.

Let's invoke the function, check out its output, and see what's the effect of changing the parameter `noise`. I'll borrow liberally from [this nice tutorial on generating scikit-learn dummy data](https://machinelearningmastery.com/generate-test-datasets-python-scikit-learn/).

Let's first call `make_circles()` with `noise=0.0` and take a look at the data. I'll use a Pandas dataframe so we can see the data in a tabular way.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

n_samples = 100
noise = 0.00

features, labels = make_circles(n_samples=n_samples, noise=noise)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=features[:,0], y=features[:,1], label=labels))
print(df.head())
#           x         y  label
# 0 -0.050232  0.798421      1
# 1  0.968583  0.248690      0
# 2 -0.809017  0.587785      0
# 3 -0.535827  0.844328      0
# 4  0.425779 -0.904827      0
```

You can see that `make_circles` returns data instances where each instance is a point with two features, x and y, and a label. Let's plot them to see how they actually look like.

```py
# Collect the points together by label, either 0 or 1
grouped = df.groupby('label')

colors = {0:'red', 1:'blue'}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', marker='.', label=key, color=colors[key])
plt.title('Points')
plt.xlim(-2, 2)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

So it looks like it's creating two concentric circles, each with a different label.

Let's increase the noise to `noise=0.05` and see the result:

```py
n_samples = 100
noise = 0.05  # <--- The only change

features, labels = make_circles(n_samples=n_samples, noise=noise)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=features[:,0], y=features[:,1], label=labels))

grouped = df.groupby('label')

colors = {0:'red', 1:'blue'}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', marker='.', label=key, color=colors[key])
plt.title('Points')
plt.xlim(-2, 2)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

It looks like the noise is added to each of the x, y coordinates to make each point shift around a little bit. When we inspect [the code for `make_circles()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.23.X/sklearn/datasets/_samples_generator.py#L602) we see that the implementation does exactly that:

```py
def make_circles( ..., noise=None, ...):

    ...
    if noise is not None:
        X += generator.normal(scale=noise, size=X.shape)
```

So now we've seen two visualizations of the dataset with two values of `noise`. But two visualizations isn't cool. You know what's cool? *Five visualizations* with the noise increasing progressively by 10x. Here's a function that does it:

```py
def make_circles_plot(n_samples, noise):

    assert n_samples > 0
    assert noise >= 0

    # Use make_circles() to generate random data points with noise.
    features, labels = make_circles(n_samples=n_samples, noise=noise)

    # Create a dataframe for later plotting.
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=features[:,0], y=features[:,1], label=labels))
    grouped = df.groupby('label')
    colors = {0:'red', 1:'blue'}

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))

    for key, group in grouped:
        group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', marker='.', label=key, color=colors[key])
    plt.title('Points with noise=%f' % noise)
    plt.xlim(-2, 2)
    plt.ylim(-2, 2)
    plt.grid()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Calling the above function with different values of `noise`, it can clearly be seen that increasing this value makes the points move around more, i.e. it makes them more "noisy", exactly as we should expect intuitively.

```py
for noise in [0.0, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0]:
    make_circles_plot(500, noise)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]